# Problem with the bevel tool because of the mirror?

Tags: edges, mirror, bevel, mirror-modifier

I used the mirror to make my chair and I wanted to round the 4 edges but impossible and I don't want to do one by one because it won't be the same

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Just select all 4 edges and then you can bevel them simultaneously with `ctrl+b`

Comment: is this what you mean with "problem"?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsdWV.png

Comment: Yes ! perfect thank you, stupid mistake